# Oracle SQL: Find most recent transaction for each ID number

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a query in Oracle SQL Developer. **Basically I want to find the record with the most recent date_transaction for each ID.** Right now my query returns up to two records for each ID, one for each status.

My current query:

```
select id, to_char(MAX(DATE_TRANSACTION),'MM/DD/YY HH24:MM:SS'), status, dkld.note
from db_name.table1_name mtlr
inner join (select * from db_name.table2_name where table_number = 308) dkld
on dkld.integer_key = mtlr.status
where id <> 0 and mtlr.date_transaction between (systimestamp - interval '1' hour) and systimestamp
group id, status, dkld.note
order by id
```

Sample query return:

```
|  ID  |  max(date_transaction)  |  Status  |    Note    |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
|  2   |    12/18/14 13:12:24    |     3    | In Transit |
|  2   |    12/18/14 13:12:22    |     4    | Arrived    |
|  3   |    12/18/14 13:12:49    |     4    | Arrived    |
|  4   |    12/18/14 13:12:05    |     3    | In Transit |
|  4   |    12/18/14 13:12:23    |     4    | Arrived    |
```

I'm really new to SQL and am not sure where to go from here. How can I narrow it down to only get the most recent record per ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
from db_name.table1_name mtlr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * from db_name.table1_name nx
  WHERE nx.id = mtlr.id
  AND nx.DATE_TRANSACTION > mtlr.DATE_TRANSACTION
  );
```

Comment: Also, some explanation of your query would be nice

Comment: IMHO no further explanation is needed. If there is no more recent thing than *this*, *this* **has to be** the most recent thing.

Answer (score 0):

Max is technically grouping the data. Since you have 4 columns and the combination of all 4 columns is unique, it will have two entries.
I haven't tested it, bit If you do below, it should return only one entry per ID  (or the concept)

```
select id, to_char(MAX(DATE_TRANSACTION),'MM/DD/YY HH24:MM:SS')
from db_name.table1_name mtlr
inner join (select * from db_name.table2_name where table_number = 308) dkld
on dkld.integer_key = mtlr.status
where id <> 0 and mtlr.date_transaction between (systimestamp - interval '1' hour) and systimestamp
group by id
order by id desc
```